# Combine JSON decoding pipeline, when response can be an array or an object at runtime

Tags: json, swift, combine

I have an API that may return a JSON array of JSON objects or a single JSON object.

How do I write a combine publisher pipeline that handles this case?

I normally hard-code the type of the JSON-response when I add my combine decode operator to my pipeline:

```
.decode(type: [MyArrayType].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
.decode(type: MyObjectType.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

Comment: This might help you: [Decode another response if first decoding failed using Combine and Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63143578/decode-another-response-if-first-decoding-failed-using-combine-and-swift)

Comment: If you can, change the API to return an array of one object. If not that, I would suggest to fix it at the decoding stage by lifting the decoding to a parent "response" object that decodes itself correctly - presumably, the downstream chain only wants to deal with one type of object. And only as a result would I solve it in a Combine pipeline - it's just doesn't feel like the right place for it

Comment: Thanks for the link @pawello2222. I'll try that. I did try to use a combine .catch operator and manually return a Publishers.Decode instance that decodes a single object in the response if decoding an array fails. But couldn't figure out how to get the generic signature for the Decode type right. It wants an "upstream" type, that I don't know hot to get at. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: @NewDev Thanks for your comment. I can't change the API (wish I could). I'm exploring  the Combine way of doing things. And I have a reusable, generic combine pipeline that can decode any array response in to a publisher that emits the elements of that response array as output values. I wanted to expand that combine pipeline to also handle cases where the response is not an array. But of course it may, as you say, be the best solution to move the logic elsewhere. Not every problem is a nail, just because you got a hammer etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to update the publisher chain and to try to decode an array of `[SomeDecodable]`, and failing that, fallback on decoding the `SomeDecodable` itself.

The pattern would be to wrap it in a `FlatMap`, and to deal with a failure inside of it.

So, let's say you have some `upstream` publisher with an output of `Data` and failure of `Error`, and you're trying to decode some generic type `T: Decodable`, this could be a way to approach:

```
upstream
  .flatMap { data in
     Just(data)
       // attempt to decode as [T]
       .decode(type: [T].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
       // if successful, publish each element one-by-one
       .flatMap { arr -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> in 
           Publishers.Sequence(sequence: arr).eraseToAnyPublisher()
       }
       // if error, attempt to decode as T, possibly failing
       .tryCatch { _ in Just(data).decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()) }
  }
  // this will be an AnyPublisher<T, Error>
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NewDev. Tried it in a Playground but I'm getting an "Ambiguous use of 'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)'" error. I'm on a MacOS 11 Beta, running Xcode 12 Beta. Here is a Gist of the code I'm trying: https://gist.github.com/weenzeel/50d91b2ba10ffb2d5d0d903ae259d7eb

Comment: That's because you're using `Just(myObjectJSONData)`, which has a failure of `Never`, whereas my example assumes an `upstream` with failure of `Error`. This creates a mismatch for `flatMap` that must match its inner return failure type with its upstream failure type. To fix, change to `Just(myObjectJSONData).setFailureType(to: Error.self)`

Comment: Combine is hard! Thanks for the support. Made the change to the gist above, but still getting the same error "Ambiguous use of 'flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)'" on line 34.

Comment: If I run it in MacOS 10.15 the gist works. I believe there are some new overloads of flatMap coming in MacOS 11. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher?changes=latest_minor

Comment: @weenzeel - ah, I see it's failing on XCode 12 Beta, but not on XCode 11. Weird... let me see

Comment: @weenzeel, XCode 12 Beta for some reason can't infer the return type without being explicit, whereas XCode 11 correctly inferred the failure type of `Publishers.Sequence`. I changed it to be more explicit with `AnyPublisher<[T], Error>`.

Comment: I'm running Xcode 12 Beta on both MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) and MacOS 11 (Big Sur). It works in Xcode 12 Beta on Catalina but not Big Sur.

Comment: @weenzeel, see the last second change. It should work. I can't test on Big Sur, but the idea is the same, and if you need, be explicit about the return type everywhere. It just makes it a bit verbose

Comment: Now it Works! Thanks for sticking with it. Now I just need to wrap my head around it :) Marked the answer as accepted for now!